# Using Anaconda Python, esp. ipython, in cygwin, esp. emacs

Tags: python, emacs, cygwin, ipython

I am working on a good Python environment for use on a Windows 7 machine.  I am a big emacs fan, and like using the windows native build that's part of cygwin (emacs-w32).  This way, I have access to all the cygwin tools from within emacs.

I also really like Anaconda's python distribution.  I really don't feature downloading and maintaining all those packages myself, esp. within cygwin.

Also a big ipython fan.

On a Linux cluster, I'm having good luck using ipython as my python interpeter within emacs.  I make a lot of plots, so matplotlib has to work too.

So I'm trying to get "ipython interpeter within cygwin emacs" to work.

- Is this a good idea?  Better ways to go?  I know there's Spyder, but I honestly like working within emacs for editing .py files.  Not just emacs keybindings - the whole emacs environment (grep, ediff, dired, etc etc).

Right now, I've gotten emacs to pick up ipython in the python 3 anaconda install.  It runs, but I get extransous characters, e.g.:

^A^BIn [^A^B1^A^B]: ^A^B

instead of In [ 1 ]:

Also figure windows tend to not work (figure appears, but Windows says Not Responding, plots don't appear).

Thanks.

Update:
Thanks for the response.  I did some more playing.  To be exact:
* Setup bash path so Anaconda python and ipython found
* Started ConEmu (windows terminal program)
* ran bash from a cmd (dos) prompt
* ran cygwin's emacs: emacs -nw -Q (no window and no customization)
* Open .py file, C-c C-z, runs Anaconda python -i
* Get these messages:
Make dedicated process? (y or n) n
Making python-shell-interpreter local to *Python* while let-bound!
Making python-shell-interpreter-args local to *Python* while let-bound!
funcall: Args out of range: "^M", 0, 2

The final line appears in the emacs "status line" at the bottom.  There is a buffer with Python running, seems to be fine.  Except Ctrl-D doesn't work.  If I type 'quit', I get the message "Use quit() or Ctrl-Z plus Return to exit."  What happened to Ctrl-D?

If I repeat the exercise with ipython, the same messages are given, ipython buffer runs, I get the random ^A^B's, Ctrl-D doesn't work.

Comment: You can probably get your interpreter by running by opening a python file, then running `C-c C-z`. It will ask you for a command to run, defaulting to `/usr/bin/python -i`. Replace that with whatever command you normally run and you should be good to go.

If you're having trouble, could you describe how you're trying to run ipython and the issue you're having in a bit more detail?

Comment: I added more info to my original post, don't know if you saw that.

Comment: For Ctrl-D, you have to use `C-c C-d` instead. This is true whenever you have a shell / interpreter inside Emacs, since `C-d` already does something (delete a char).

For the `^A^B` problem, you might be able to fix it my running `ipython -i --colors=NoColor`.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  C-c C-d and C-d both don't work.  --colors=NoColor got rid of ^A^B.  Figure windows still don't work - no plot shown, windows says that window is not responding, yes I had ion() on and tried show().  So, it seems my desired workflow of running ipython as a process within emacs on Windows isn't common.  It works fine for me on Linux, and in general is a very powerful approach.  Why reinvent the wheel for an IDE with Spyder when emacs already exists?  So, do people do this?  Why has it so far not been possible for me to get this working?

Comment: Hm, not sure how you can fix the `C-c C-d` problem, you should probably just put up with it. I don't know anything about ipython, is the graph ipython creates drawn in text (as ascii art), or shown as a proper image? Most likely it's trying to show an image, which is failing because Emacs and your Cygwin setup is text-only. Does ipython work outside Emacs (but inside Cygwin)?

Comment: @Brian that was a very interesting comment one year later.I'm evaluating a similar setup and I wonder if in 2017 there is a better way to set this all up on windows (apart from running a linux VM).

Comment: @user1712447 funny you should add a comment.  I'm currently using mostly Spyder, which is a nice IDE but editor is lacking compared to emacs.  On that front, I can use the emacs package elpy and run ipythong inside emacs.  Unsolved problem is I can't get matplotlib figure windows to work.  I've put that on hold for now.

Comment: @D_Strozzi have you considered using emacs on windows? Outside the cygwin ecosystem.

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm doing now.  I run the GNU "official" win32 build of emacs.  This is where I get figure windows net responding when I run ipython.  The window comes up, nothing is displayed, window title says "not responding."